# Save checkout custom field merging the value to an existing field in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, custom-fields

I have created the following custom checkout field for WooCommerce, based on all the examples that can be found.

- Billing house number `billing_houseno`
- Shipping house number `shipping_houseno`

Output shows an address field (street) and house number field. Works perfectly fine. Stores data nicely in a custom house number field and Address works like it normally does - of course.

I'd like to merge the following fields in one:

- `billing_address_1` and `billing_houseno` in `billing_address_1` existing field.
- `shipping_address_1` and `shipping_houseno` in `shipping_address_1` existing field.

So it will combine both fields in one database field.

Is there a way to store both fields in one existing field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Update:**

> In your comment code link, there is some errors in your code:

> 1. In your bones_add_field_and_reorder_fields function, you are unsetting billing and shipping company, but after few lines down, you are trying to set those values in:

> ```
> $newfields['billing']['billing_company']   = $fields['billing']['billing_company'];
> ```

```
$newfields['shipping']['shipping_company'] = $fields['shipping']['shipping_company'];
```

> And it's **throwing some errors**… 
> You should **not** unset `'billing_company'` and `'shipping_company'`.

> 2. Everywhere you are using `$order->id` and it should be replaced by `$order->get_id()`.

> 3. I have tested everything with your updated code and my updated function below. **It works**…

Using a custom function hooked in **`woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta`** action hook, you will be able to merge the values.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'custom_checkout_field_update_order_meta', 10, 2 );
function custom_checkout_field_update_order_meta( $order_id ) {
    $separator = '. '; // Separator for merged fields

    // Billing fields
    $billing_address_1 = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['billing_address_1'] );
    $billing_houseno   = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['billing_houseno'] );

    if( ! ( empty($billing_address_1) && empty($billing_houseno) ) )
        update_post_meta( $order_id, '_billing_address_1', $billing_address_1 . $separator . $billing_houseno );

    $shipping_address_1 = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['shipping_address_1'] );
    $shipping_houseno   = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['shipping_houseno'] );

    if( ! ( empty($shipping_address_1) && empty($shipping_houseno) ) )
        update_post_meta( $order_id, '_shipping_address_1', $shipping_address_1 . $separator . $shipping_houseno );
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of the active child theme (or active theme).

This time, this is tested and works.

Comment: Thanks @LoicTheAztec for your comment. Really nice example, but it still doesn't work for me. Let me show you how I build my custom field, maybe I'm doing something wrong.

Hereby the link to my codeshare: https://codeshare.io/5wq7N9

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @julien I have tested everything and updated my answer. It works. BUT there is some errors in your linked code , see my update notes... Thanks.

Comment: Ah sorry, I removed it accidentally! My bad :)

Comment: @Juliën Thanks julien… I was just very surprised.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'my_custom_checkout_field_update_order_meta' );

function my_custom_checkout_field_update_order_meta( $order_id ) {
    if ( ! empty( $_POST['billing_houseno'] ) ) {
        $billing_houseno = $_POST['billing_houseno'];
        $billing_address_1 = $_POST['billing_address_1'];
        $new_billing_address = $billing_houseno.'.'.$billing_address_1;
        update_post_meta( $order_id, '_billing_address_1', $new_billing_address );
    }
    if(!empty($_POST['shipping_houseno'])){
        $shipping_houseno = $_POST['shipping_houseno'];
        $shipping_address_1 = $_POST['shipping_address_1'];
        $new_shipping_address = $shipping_houseno.'.'.$shipping_address_1;
        update_post_meta( $order_id, '_shipping_address_1', $new_shipping_address );    
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'customise_checkout_field_update_order_meta',10,2);

function customise_checkout_field_update_order_meta($order_id, $posted_data)
{
//write your code here to update custom data.
}
```